# Habilitar red en CentOS 7 desde VMware

Tags: virtualbox, centos, virtualización, virtualhost

recientemente instalé Centos 7 (x86) en una maquina virtual con VMware, el problema está en que no tengo red, al hacer ifconfig solo me dice que tengo configurado el archivo lo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además al revisar en /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ no veo ningun otro archivo para la red, en teoria deberia aparecer algo como ifcfg-eth0 o algo parecido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el host está bien configurado? Tiene las conexiones puente? El guest tiene habilitada la red?

Answer (score 3):

Una vez seleccionada tu maquina virtual puedes hacer click en VM > Settings
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez hecho esto, en la pestaña Hardware, selecciona Network Adapter en la tabla, a la derecha aparecera el apartado Network connection.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo otra maquina virtual la cual configuré de esa manera y tampoco me funcionó.